# use 1 line of code instead of the use the same code

Tags: c#, class

I have code like this:

```
string FileName = "Users.json";
var DeserializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { AllowTrailingCommas = true };
string jsonstring = File.ReadAllText(FileName);
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(jsonstring, DeserializeOptions);
```

Root is list of 2 objects: Monsters and People. I use these 4 lines of code in my win forms program more than 10 times. Is it possible to change this code for class and use in other .cs files using shorter code?

Comment: What do you mean by "change this code for class"? You can certainly put that code into a method and call it from everywhere... have you tried doing that? If so, but you've run into problems, please show what you've tried and clarify what issue you're facing.

Comment: Are you meaning that sometimes you deserialize a `Root` and sometimes a `Foo` and sometimes a `Bar` and you want a method that takes a filename and gives you a Whatever?

Comment: Or if you mean literally a 1 line: `var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(File.ReadAllText("Users.json"), new JsonSerializerOptions { AllowTrailingCommas = true });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - put your code into a method:

```cs
internal static class MyUtilities
{
    public static Root DoMyStuff()
    {
        string FileName = "Users.json";
        var DeserializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { AllowTrailingCommas = true };
        string jsonstring = File.ReadAllText(FileName);
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(jsonstring, DeserializeOptions);
    }
}
```

Depending on your use case and the case your code varies across those different instances (not sure whether it is 100% the same, or uses different filenames, for example), you may want to accept some of those values as parameters.

In any case, you can then replace all of your code by single lines like this:

```
var result = MyUtilities.DoMyStuff();
```

Comment: But wouldn't one instead just deser once and then share the result around the app?

Comment: I think maybe public static Root DoMyStuff(string FileName) could be better???

Comment: @CaiusJard: I suspect that it's not always 100% the same code being run, but as the OP did not elaborate on that, I can only guess to what extent the result of the method remains the same. It might, for instance, also change by time.

Comment: @Serge: As I wrote, it's not clear from the question whether the filename (or anything else) is variable.

Comment: Yes, I am agree, the OP disappered as usual. I mean something like this public static Root DoMyStuff(string FileName="User.json").  It could be made generic too if you replace Root by <T>

Comment: @Serge: We could also pass in optional delegates to invoke custom deserializers and read the content from other sources than a file. And we could accept an optional serializer options object, for cases where a deviation from the `AllowTrailingCommas` setting and other options is desirable. We might also accept a JSON property path to return a sub-object contained within the returned object. All of these and more are ways to make the method more flexible, possibly even more reusable - but without any more specific info, there's no way to tell which ones of these are benefitial in context, ...

Comment: ... versus making the code unnecessarily hard to read and debug because the added flexibility is not actually needed in the project at hand.